# Put LI with "active" class first in UL

Tags: jquery

i have an unordered list like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="first"><a href="/nl"><span>Nederlands</span></a></li> 
  <li class="active"><a href="/fr"><span>Français</span></a></li> 
  <li class="last"><a href="/de"><span>Deutch</span></a></li> 
</ul>
```

I need the LI which has the class "active" to be first in the list nomatter what its original position was.
Anyone a suggestions on how to do this with jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`prependTo`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo):

```
$('li.active').prependTo('ul');
```

You should probably give an ID to the `ul` and use that in the `prependTo` call.

[See jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duuA8/).

Comment: shouldn't you take it out of it's original position too?

Comment: @JMC Creative No, you don't need to. You are moving the element, not cloning it.

Answer (score 2):

```
var $active = $('li.active');
$active.prependTo($active.parent());
```

reference: [.prependTo()](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/)

demo: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/44/